# Remove duplicate value in dart

Tags: json, dart, flutter

I'm the newbie in dart and flutter. I have try any code of javascript to solve it, but it's doesn't work:(.

I want get length of orders, but I don't want get the same value from the destination.id. Any idea for this case? Is possible to use library queries.dart or anything for solve this case?

This is my JSON data.

```
{
    "data": {
        "shipments": [
            {
                "id": "1608",
                "orders": [
                    {
                        "destination": {
                            "id": "979"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "destination": {
                            "id": "979"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "destination": {
                            "id": "1074"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "destination": {
                            "id": "1074"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "destination": {
                            "id": "1022"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "destination": {
                            "id": "1022"
                        }
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "1599",
                "orders": [
                    {
                        "destination": {
                            "id": "979"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "destination": {
                            "id": "979"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "destination": {
                            "id": "1660"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "destination": {
                            "id": "1660"
                        }
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
var data = ... your JSON data ...;
List orders = data["data"]["shipments"]["orders"];
var uniqueIds = orders.map((o) => o["destination"]["id"]).toSet();
var uniqueCount = uniqueIds.length;
```

This collects the unique IDs in a `Set`, which ensures that duplicates are ignored, and counts them.

Comment: Thanks dude, its works :D

I added the if statement in map(), like this => `if (o["destination"] == null) {
                        return 0;
                      } else {
                        return o["destination"]["id"];
                      }`  Is that clear?

Comment: It makes sense if some elements in "orders" do not have a destination (the example suggested that they all do). Remember to remove the `0` from the set afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the function groupBy from the collection package. It will neatly collect all duplicates in a map of lists with the id as the key.

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

List orders = data["data"]["shipments"]["orders"];
var newMap = groupBy(orders, (obj) => obj['destination']['id']);
var length = newMap.length;
print("$newMap, length: $length");
```

Output:

```
{
    979: [
        {destination: {id: 979
            }
        },
        {destination: {id: 979
            }
        }
    ],
    1074: [
        {destination: {id: 1074
            }
        },
        {destination: {id: 1074
            }
        }
    ],
    1022: [
        {destination: {id: 1022
            }
        },
        {destination: {id: 1022
            }
        }
    ]
},
length: 3
```