# Remove duplicates from Json response flutter

Tags: flutter

i am unable to remove duplicates in Json. In below Json if title field has same values, i need to remove the duplicate node. IN below json title named "car" was repeated 3 times and i need to remove duplicates based on title field. I followed below stackoverflow links but not solved my problem.

[Remove duplicate value in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54087857/remove-duplicate-value-in-dart)

Actual Json:

```
{
    "totalSize": 6,
    "done": true,
    "records": [{
            "attributes": {
                "type": "ContentVersion",
                "url": "https://sampleUrl"
            },
            "Id": "123456",
            "Title": "car",
            "Team_Category__c": "Vehicle"
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "ContentVersion",
                "url": "https://sampleUrl"
            },
            "Id": "123456",
            "Title": "car",
            "Team_Category__c": "Vehicle"
        },

        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "ContentVersion",
                "url": "https://sampleUrl"
            },
            "Id": "123456",
            "Title": "cycle",
            "Team_Category__c": "Vehicle"
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "ContentVersion",
                "url": "https://sampleUrl"
            },
            "Id": "123456",
            "Title": "aeroplane",
            "Team_Category__c": "Vehicle"
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "ContentVersion",
                "url": "https://sampleUrl"
            },
            "Id": "123456",
            "Title": "car",
            "Team_Category__c": "Vehicle"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you please describe the relation to flutter? If you get this json as a response from your database you would just read out the data you need and don't need to remove anything...

Comment: In my database, i have problem some title fields with same name are repeating. When parsing the json from mobile application ios flutter, i want to manipulate the the Json to remove duplicates using set feature in dart. Below link is also similar to my problem, but not solved for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54087857/remove-duplicate-value-in-dart

Comment: the duplicates would be removed if you convert it to a map

Comment: Can you please share sample code like below      var newUniqueResponse = jsonResponseArray.map((records) => [records.title]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `kt_dart:` to your pubspec.

Then import it in your dart file `import 'package:kt_dart/kt.dart';`

Then:

```
var json = jsonDecode(yourJsonAsString);
var records = mutableListFrom(json["records"]);
var distinct = records.distinctBy((it) => it["Title"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

if nothing works out, you can create new similar structure and add only distinct items into it as below. I am not a dart programmer but it is a naive solution.

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {

  var jsonData = '[{ "name" : "Dane", "alias" : "FilledStacks" },{ "name" : "Dane", "alias" : "FilledStacks" }]';

  List uniqueList = new List();
  List parsedJson = json.decode(jsonData);
  
  for (var jsonElement in parsedJson) {

    bool isPresent = false;
    for (var uniqueEle in uniqueList) {
      if (uniqueEle['name'] == jsonElement['name']) isPresent = true;
    }
    if (!isPresent) uniqueList.add(jsonElement);
  }
  
print('$uniqueList');

  print('');

  print('${parsedJson.runtimeType} : $parsedJson');

}
```